# POST request return 409 along with object

Tags: rest, api

I am building (modifying) a REST API POST end-point. When client send a post request to my end-point and it detect a duplicate, then server should return 409 instead of 201. I get this part.

My question is, under above situation, should the server also send the existing object along with 409 or just wait for client send another GET request to get the existing object (assuming client can handle this)?

If it is the latter one, then how does client know which object to request, since it doesn't get an ID or GUID from previous POST request?

I want to know what is the standard or preferred way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another trick is to reply with HTTP-308 so clients can automatically follow the redirection to the existing resource, if the automatic follow feature is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [RFC-7231 on HTTP 409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8),

> The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict.

So I think returning the existing object is a good solution, although you should reflect on the security implications.

Alternatives would include returning the name/path of the field on which there is a conflict, with or without the associated value.